# Change while condition depending on other condition - Python

Tags: python

I need to create a condition depending on another if statement. 
How can I save a condition within a variable?

```
 while campo=="nome" or campo=="alc" or campo=="diff" or campo=="gen" or campo=="bicchiere" or campo=="prep" or campo=="img":
     if err>0:
         print("Inserisci un campo valido")
     campo=input("Quale campo di %s vuoi cambiare?  (I campi sono nome, alc, diff, gen, bicchiere, prep, img)" %nome)
     err+=1
 if campo=="nome":
     condition= modifica.isalpha()
 elif campo=="alc":
     condition= "modifica=!'Y' or modifica'N'"

 while modifica is None or condition is False:
     modifica=input("In cosa vuoi cambiare il campo %s di %s? " %(campo,nome))
```

Comment: What's wrong with just storing it as `True` or `False`?

Comment: Please don't post commented code.

Comment: @voidlife I have to check that saved condition in the following loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can assign a function to `condition`. If there's no named function that does what you want, you can use a `lambda`.

```
 while campo not in {"nome", "alc", "diff", "gen", "bicchiere", "prep", "img"}:
     if err>0:
         print("Inserisci un campo valido")
     campo=input("Quale campo di %s vuoi cambiare?  (I campi sono nome, alc, diff, gen, bicchiere, prep, img)" %nome)
     err+=1
 if campo=="nome":
     condition = str.isalpha
 elif campo=="alc":
     condition = lambda m: m == 'Y' or m == 'N' 

 while modifica is None or not condition(modifica):
     modifica=input("In cosa vuoi cambiare il campo %s di %s? " %(campo,nome))
```

Comment: Hello. Thank you very much for your help. Sadly by putting isalpha as condition I get unsolved reference error

Comment: Sorry, thatt should be `str.isalpha`.